# how to fix an error that appears only if i create a function with a for loop inside, istead of using for loop without creating a function?

Tags: python, function, random-forest

im creating a random forest for regression. i had to one-hot encode object columns in my dataset 'x' so i used a for loop to iterate through it to find object columns and printed the results (it was succsesful). i then ran train_test_split and fed it to the regressor succsesfully. but when i tried to create a function for the same purpose instead of just using a for loop, i called it, then fed it to the regressor, and the error popped out:  could not convert string to float. (there were string values in the dataset, but i thought i already converted them to numeric). where is the mistake?

#### my function which doesnt work with the regressor

```
 def obj_col (column,x):
    for column in x:
        if x[column].dtype == 'object':
            x[column] = pd.get_dummies(x, columns=[column])
            return x
```

```
x = obj_col(column,x)
```

#### just a for loop which works with regressor

```
for column in x:
        if x[column].dtype == 'object':
            x[column] = pd.get_dummies(x, columns=[column])
```

#### train and test

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, 
random_state=0)
```

#### regressor

```
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100, random_state = 0) 
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Your function has an argument `column` but you are overwriting it in the very first line.

Comment: why are using `for` loop if you have `column` detail with you?